# Como poner fondo transparente a AccordionView?

Tags: java, android, xml, accordion

Buenas tardes estoy usando una libreria para android studio que me ayude en listas tipo acordion y esta es la libreria:

[Enlace de la libreria accordion_view de riyagayasen](https://github.com/riyagayasen/Android_accordion_view)

el problema que es que he tratado de ponerle un color de fondo al Head y tambien al body (Paragraf como le llaman) pero el color que quiero ponerle es un blanco con alfa es decir blanco semi transparente #33fffffff , pero este color no me agarra no puedo ver el fondo de mi pantalla(Activity) del elemento padre.

este es el xml que tengo donde declaro el AccordionView:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" // COLOR ROSADO
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_230" >



            </fragment>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

              android:background="@color/color_semi_transparente_negro"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                >

                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/txvUbicacionPrincipal"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:text="ubicacion especifica"
                       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                       android:textColor="@color/color_blanco"
                       />


                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/txvUbicacionGenerica"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:text="ubicacion generica"

             android:layout_below="@+id/txvUbicacionPrincipal"
                       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_15"
                       android:textColor="@color/color_blanco"
                       />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

      <com.riyagayasen.easyaccordion.AccordionView
          android:id="@+id/acordion_schudele"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:isAnimated="true"
          app:heading="Horario"
          app:isExpanded="true"
          app:isPartitioned="true"

          >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Demo accordion text" />

          <Button
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Test Button"
              android:id="@+id/button_2"
              android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />
          <Button
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Test Button 2"
              android:layout_below="@+id/button_2" />

      </com.riyagayasen.easyaccordion.AccordionView>



    </LinearLayout>
```

Bueno ese es el xml donde pongo mi accordion

esto es lo que he intentado:

1:

```
<com.riyagayasen.easyaccordion.AccordionView
          android:id="@+id/acordion_schudele"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:bodyBackgroundColor="#33000000" // he puesto esto pero 
          // nada al parecer hay un fondo blanco por mas debajo que no 
          //he logrado encontrar
          app:isAnimated="true"
          app:heading="Horario"
          app:isExpanded="true"
          app:isPartitioned="true">
```

2:
  he intentado ponerlo por medio de codigo pero tampoco nada

```
     this.accordionViewSchud.setHeadingBackGroundColor
    (R.color.color_semi_transparente_blanco);
    this.accordionViewSchud.setBodyBackGroundColor
    (R.color.color_semi_transparente_blanco);
```

3:he entrado al propio xml accordion.xml que viene incluido en esa libreria y modifique agregandoles background poniendoles fondos transparentes pero aun nada , no se como encontrar ese fondo blanco.

no se si de algo sirve mi build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sbcclub"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
 optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

//implementaciones para google maps

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'

//IMPLEMENTACIONES PARA RECYCLERVIEW

 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
 implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

 ///

 //implementaciones para EasyAcordion


 implementation 'com.riyagayasen.android:easyaccordion:1.0.3'

 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
 }
```

ENTONCES PARA FINALIZAR AL FINAL LO QUE QUIERO ES PODER PONERLE TANTO AL BODY(PARAGRAF) Y HEADING DEL ACCORDION EL COLOR SEMI TRANSPARENTE DE COLOR BLANCO COSA QUE PUEDA VER MI FONDO DE MI LINEARLAYOUT QUE ES ROSADO PERO NO SUCEDE ESO , SOLO SE MESCLA AL PARECER CON UN FONDO BLANCO QUE NO PUEDO IDENTIFICARLO.

MUCHAS GRACIAS.

Answer (score 0):

la libreria esta usando un xml como background llamado accordion_background.xml, creo que podrias sobre escribirlo y ponerle fonde transparente.

Aca te dejo el contenido del xml:

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#BDBDBD"/>  <-- este es el problema
        <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/> <-- este es el problema
        <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Si pero te cuento que al correr la app se vuelve a su mismo color (por defecto al que esta ahorita) te cuento no se xq sera q esta libreria llama a su servidor o algo o no se q magia habra ahi gracias de todos modos

Comment: y... la libreria esta abandonada hace 3 años, yo no recomiendo que uses una libreria que no fue actualizada en los ultimos 6 meses

Comment: pues si al parecer si , lastimosamente meti la pata y ya no hay vuelta atras. ha usado alguna ves esta libreria :  https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view   @Erick Silva